# cp all files and subdirectories in a directory ksh

Tags: ksh, cp

How can I do a `cp` to copy all files including all sub-directories in the current directory.

I looked at the man page, but I can't figure out how to do it.

EDIT:
(my *nix is Linux)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

What *nix do you have?

Under Linux you use normally:

```
cp -r <source> <target>
```

and if you want to copy all the same attributes (aka owner, etc.):

```
cp -a <source> <target>
```

Answer (score 2):

`cp -r dir1 dir2`

```
-R, -r, --recursive
          copy directories recursively
```

Comment: Sorry, tell me if I'm wrong but, it will copy all subdirectories recursively ? So it'll copy all the files located in them in my current directory ?